# Qtimer vs timerEvent - which of them produces less overhead?

Tags: qt, timer

I need a timer to be triggered every 1 ms. [This](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html) document reports, that slot invocation may be much slower than even a virtual function call.

But if we compare signals/slots with event occurance, what mechanism will be faster, more efficient and produce less overhead: `QTimer` with it's `timeout()` signal connected to a slot or bare `QObject::startTimer()`\ `QObject::killTimer()` with `QObject::timerEvent()`?

Will the answer for above question be the same for Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`QTimer` is actually just a signal-slot wrapper around the `QObject::startTimer()` functionality, so it will undoubtedly have more overhead associated with it on all platforms (it internally implements `QObject::timerEvent()` -- its implementation of this function is just to emit the `timeout()` signal).

Of note, `QBasicTimer` is a more light-weight wrapper around the `QObject::startTimer()` functionality.  If you use `QBasicTimer`, you still have to implement `QObject::timerEvent()`, but it manages the timer ID for you.  As such, a `QBasicTimer` combines some of the ease-of-use of a `QTimer` with the efficiency of using the `QObject::startTimer()` mechanism.

Comment: On linux QBasicTimer with 0 timeout to update a QGLWidget is ~0.2msecs faster than QTimer on my machine - thanks :D

Answer (score 7):

As a matter of fact, if you need precision, QT does not guaranteed that your timer gets executed exactly after 1ms.

At least until QT 4.7.X if QT has an event (processed inside the event loop) all timers are checked for expiration internally (and then raised their signals) "in the event loop". I mean, they won't be executed as a OS event that interrupts other tasks, etc.

What you could get is a timer executed after 1.5 secs if any other 3 events in your loop need for example 0.5 sec each.

I hope that my memory is not failing, I took a look at QT timers code some months ago and now I can't remember if timer events are processed after other events or before.

Hope this helps you a bit more.

Comment: I supposed to ask my next question right about this. Thank you!